# Disable error prone in bazel

Tags: bazel, errorprone

I have a project with a lot of code. Some of this code doesn't pass error-prone inspections turned on by default in Bazel. I want to disable error-prone in bazel. Is it possible to do it without adding a command line argument via the WORKSPACE file?

P.S. Disabling via command line works well

Comment: Try adding the command in your `bazelrc`, bazel will read it when compiling the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Xiao Liang mentioned, you can add `--javacopt="-XepDisableAllChecks"` to your `bazelrc`, or you can also add it to `tools/bazel.rc` inside your workspace so that it can be checked in with the source code. Note though that this will disable error prone for all java builds in the workspace. You can instead use [java_binary.javacopts](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_binary.javacopts) or [java_library.javacopts](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_library.javacopts) to disable error prone for specific binaries or libraries, which would allow error prone to run on other parts of the build.