# How to exclude error prone from being run on unit tests?

Tags: java, maven-compiler-plugin, errorprone

When `maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile @ foo-child` runs, thread dumps show errorprone is taking an extremely long time. I believe there is a bug with errorprone, but for now I'd rather just have errorprone not run on unit tests.

I have a parent pom.xml:

```
<modules>
  <module>foo-child</module>
</modules>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
    <artifactId>error_prone_annotations</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  // also has dependency for io.norberg auto-matter and com.google.auto.value auto-value
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        // also has annotationProcessorPaths configuration for auto-matter and auto-value
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Is there anything I can put in the foo-child pom.xml that will allow me to exclude `maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile @ foo-child` from being run at all.

I cannot exclude error prone completely because other things like guava depend on it.

**EDIT: Seems like [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/error-prone-discuss/espWBBaqV2Y) user is trying to solve the same problem. Do you know how I could apply the solution given there to my case?**

Comment: Why ignore failed tests?  Fix the issue!  If the failure is from a concrete dependency then mock it for the sake of having consistent tests.  But somebody has to fix the issue.

Comment: Who said anything about failed tests? The testCompile is taking an extremely long time - many minutes on only a few hundred lines of code. The cpu is during this time is being used by error prone. I just want to compile the tests and not have error prone be used on unit test files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use error prone's command line flag to disable checks: [-XepDisableAllChecks](https://errorprone.info/docs/flags)

Similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934782/disable-error-prone-in-bazel) for disabling error prone in bazel

> add --javacopt="-XepDisableAllChecks" to your bazelrc

For specific test(s) use `-XepExcludedPaths`:

> you can completely exclude certain paths from any Error Prone checking via the -XepExcludedPaths flag
>
> ```
> -XepExcludedPaths:.*/build/generated/.*
> ```

Comment: But I only want to disable the checks on a specific test file

Comment: @lf215 you can completely exclude certain paths from any Error Prone checking via the -XepExcludedPaths flag

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) plugin for this.

Comment: This keeps the test(s) from running altogether.  OP wants to exclude *Error-Prone*, not the test(s).

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `-XepExcludedPaths` compiler option to your maven build.

https://errorprone.info/docs/flags

Answer (score 0):

You can add maven profile to `foo-child` module which will run the build without errorprone. Also you can make the activation of that profile dependent from some parameter and set that parameter's value in parent pom.